# VueJS: Analyze content of a slot with components before they are mounted

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Let's say we have a component `<my-cp :list="list"></my-cp>`

With this kind of template:

```
<div class="container">
  <slot></slot> 
  <my-cp2 v-for="li in list" :my-data="li.data"></my-cp2>
</div>
```

My question: Is it possible to initialise my component `my-cp` either with list as an array or using HTML?

I mean having both possibilities. In this case, the HTML would look like this:

```
<my-cp>
  <my-cp2 my-data="foo">
  <my-cp2 my-data="bar">
</my-cp>
```

I am trying to analyze the content of the slot before it is mounted but it seems I can only access the element once the child component is already mounted.

Comment: Do you mean you want to use the slot content if someone provided it with a default as a fallback?

Comment: Exactly! Thanks for the translation :)

Comment: Sorry, no "with a default as a fallback", but "as a fallback". I mean the slot doesn't have default content, but if content is provided it should be used as fallback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your default content *inside* the slot in your component. If the user adds slot content, their content will show. Otherwise, the slot content will show.

```
<div class="container">
  <slot>
    <my-cp2 v-for="li in list" :my-data="li.data"></my-cp2>
  </slot> 
</div>
```

Here is an [example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/RVgLrx?editors=1010).

### Edit

After further discussion in the comments, I believe I understand what you want to do. To clarify for future readers, as I understand it, @Nabab wants to be able to initialize his component using either data coming from a property, or from components rendered in the HTML in the slot for the component. Additionally the component should be able to modify the existing data to add more items to it's list.

You can do this using a render function.

```
Vue.component("my-cp",{
  props:["list"],
  data(){
    return {
      internalList: this.list
    }
  },
  render(h){
    let workingList = []

    // Examine the default slot, and if there are any parse
    // them and add the data to the workingList
    if (this.$slots.default){
      for (node of this.$slots.default)
        // May want to check here if the node is a myCp2,
        // otherwise, grab the data
         workingList.push(node.componentOptions.propsData.myData)
    }

    // Add any items that came from the property/internal data
    workingList = workingList.concat(this.internalList)

    // Create a list of myCp2 vnodes with the correct data
    const list = workingList.map(n => h(myCp2, {props:{myData:n}}))

    // Create a button to add list items
    const btn = h("button", {on:{click:() => this.internalList.push({bar: true})}}, "Add")

    //Render
    return h("div", [list, btn])
  },
})
```

Here is an [example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/JNJvYq?editors=1010).

Comment: Yes, but after it is mounted I will not be able to add an element in my list. The goal is to keep the v-for on the list. The slot is only for initialisation, but once mounted I want to keep the possibility of adding new elements by pushing them in the list array.

Comment: @Nabab Do you mean that in some cases, you might not get `list` as a property and instead want to initialize it from the contents of the slot?

Comment: That's exactly that

Comment: @Nabab Let me think about that. You can access what is in the slot using `this.$slots.default` (if it is not a named slot). From there you can look at the nodes, but you would end up parsing it yourself I expect.

Comment: The problem is that you cannot access the slot's original content, I tried every event and either it doesn't exist or it's already mounted. What I would have liked in fact is to analyse the content of the slot before it is mounted, remove its content and add each element to my `list` array. It might work with a regular `div`, but I have to check I can interpret methods coming from the properties.

Comment: @Nabab I've updated the answer. I think this works the way you want.